# Why when i add a select option to select the form field doesn't change to valid?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I have this code and when i add this selected option the form field remains invalid and never change the state. I've tried multiple methods from the  form instance and none worked.

```
  $scope.disDeLoca = true;
  $scope.deLocalidad = "Ciudad Autonoma de Buenos Aires";
  $("select[name='localidadDos'] > option").remove();
        $("select[name='localidadDos']").append(
          '<option selected="true" value="C0001" disabled="true">Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires</option>'
  );
  $scope.disBarrioDe = true;
  $scope.disSrchBtnDe = true;
  $("#deLocalidad").val("Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you disable that option by using `disable="true"` then it will remain disabled untill you enable it again.

So, remove this code: `disabled=true`

```js
$("select[name='localidadDos'] > option").remove();

  $("select[name='localidadDos']").append('<option value="C0002" disabled>I am disabled</option>');     
  $("select[name='localidadDos']").append('<option value="C0002">Ciudad Autónoma de Aires</option>');
  $("select[name='localidadDos']").append('<option selected="true" value="C0001">Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires</option>');
  $("select[name='localidadDos']").append('<option value="C0003">Ciudad de Buenos Aires</option>');
  
$("#deLocalidad").val("Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires");

$('#form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <select name="localidadDos" required>
    <option>This is an example</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```